# Apache Spark 1.3 dataframe SaveAsTable database other then default

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to save a dataframe as table using [saveAsTable](http://people.apache.org/~tdas/spark-1.3.0-temp-docs/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#saveAsTable(java.lang.String)) and well it works but I want to save the table to not the default database, Does anyone know if there is a way to set the database to use? I tried with hiveContext.sql("use db_name") and this did not seem to do it. There is an [saveAsTable](http://people.apache.org/~tdas/spark-1.3.0-temp-docs/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#saveAsTable(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode,%20scala.collection.immutable.Map)) that takes in some options. Is there a way that i can do it with the options?

Answer (score 5):

It does not look like you can set the database name yet... if you read the [HiveContext.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/85ee0cabe87a27b6947c2d3e8525f04c77f80f6f/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.scala) code you see a lot comments like...

```
    // TODO: Database support...
```

So I am guessing that its not supported yet.

Update:

In spark 1.5.1 this works, which did not work in early versions. In early version you had to use a using statement like in deformitysnot answer.

```
 df.write.format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("databaseName.tablename")
```

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed in Spark 1.5 and you can do it using :

```
hiveContext.sql("USE sparkTables");
dataFrame.saveAsTable("tab3", "orc", SaveMode.Overwrite);
```

By the way in Spark 1.5 you can read Spark saved dataframes from Hive command line (beeline, ...), something that was impossible in earlier versions.